# Haskell with IO monad error, from IO to basic type

Tags: haskell

I have this function:

```
onData :: IO ([Float]) -> IO ()
onData vals =
    do
    let res = liftM fsum vals
    putStrLn " * Processing ... "
    putStrLn res
    putStrLn " * Sum : "
    putStrLn " * Done Processing"
    return ()

    fsum :: [Float] -> Float
    fsum []     = 0
    fsum (x:xs) = x + fsum(xs)
```

And this function, I am getting an error at the 'fsum' call.  What am I missing?  I just want the value returned.

```
HaskellParseData.hs:20:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `IO Float'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: IO Float
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `res'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: putStrLn res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`liftM fsum vals` has type `IO Float`. You're giving it a name with `let res = ...`, but later trying to use it as a `Float`. You should *bind* it instead, producing a `Float` as desired, using `<-`:

```
res <- liftM fsum vals
```

It would be more idiomatic for `onData` to take a `[Float]` instead; you can sequence the action that produces this data elsewhere. Then you could simply use:

```
let res = fsum vals
```

Answer (score 1):

GHC is inferring from the `putStrLn` that `res` must be a `String`.

Change `putStrLn res` to `putStrLn $ show res`.

(What ehird says is true too.)

Comment: Yes, that's why I edited my answer. Just making your change also doesn't work: "Couldn't match expected type `String` against inferred type `Float` // In the first argument of `putStrLn`, namely `res`"

Comment: Oh, sorry; I misinterpreted your answer. Yes, you're completely correct.